# How to create app in Django in Visual Studio Code terminal?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I wrote this command into a VSCode terminal:

```
python manage.py startapp shop
```

I was expecting it to create a new Django app but it threw an error like this:

```
C:\Users\vpolo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\vpolo\Documents\courses\manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

Comment: Please check if the path is correct according to the error report.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be of the path check the filename and the correct relative path in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You should write the command in the path which has manage.py
If you created a project with the name shop with this command

```
django-admin startproject shop
```

path of the manage.py will be in shop/shop

If you don't need the nested shop, use this command

```
django-admin startproject shop .
```

full stop doesn't create a nested project, then manage.py will be in the path ../shop/